# Selecting Min/Max from Comma Separated Values against each record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

consider below table and its records

```
create table dbo.test
(
id  numeric(4),
vals    nvarchar(1000)
);

insert into dbo.test values (1,'1,2,3,4,5');
insert into dbo.test values (2,'6,7,8,9,0');
insert into dbo.test values (3,'11,54,76,23');
```

I am going to use below function to split CSVs, you can use any method to help in `select` syntax

```
CREATE FUNCTION [aml].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))     
as     
begin     
declare @idx int     
declare @slice varchar(8000)     

select @idx = 1     
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return     

while @idx!= 0     
begin     
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)     
    if @idx!=0     
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)     
    else     
        set @slice = @String     

    if(len(@slice)>0)
        insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)     

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)     
    if len(@String) = 0 break     
end 
return     
end
```

I want to select `id` and `max` and `min` values from `vals` against each record.

**Update** Though i am writing the query on SQL Server 2008 but i need to support SQL Server 2005 and above

Comment: Your function returns tables so you just need to insert those values with corresponding ID in some temp table and you can do group by to find MIN and MAX value for each ID.

Comment: if you are planning to use a splitter, check out [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `CROSS APPLY` to the table projected by the function and then apply normal aggregation functions on each group of `id` :

```
SELECT t.id, MIN(CAST(x.items AS INT)) AS MinItem, MAX(CAST(x.items AS INT)) AS MaxItem
FROM dbo.test t 
     CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(t.vals, ',') x
GROUP BY t.id;
```

(**Edit** - since these appear to be integers, you'll want to cast before applying the `MIN / MAX` aggregates otherwise you'll get an alphanumeric sort)

[SqlFiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfa8c/9)

Another option is to persist the comma separated list in a normalized table structure before applying queries over them - it isn't useful storing non-normalized data in an RDBMS :)

Comment: [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.90).aspx) is available to Sql 2005.

Comment: I need to support SQL Server 2005 to 2012

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - CROSS APPLY was introduced in Sql 2005, so you are good to go. I've added CASTS to INT.

Comment: It is working on the fiddle but it is giving error "Incorrect syntax near '.'." when i am trying on my machine (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: I don't understand why i am getting "incorrect syntax" error

Comment: I'm guessing your actual query is more complex. Can you upload it to SqlFiddle and we can have a look at it?

Comment: No, still getting the error, i changed the query. calling the function in select clause.

Answer (score 3):

Without function, just plain `sql`:

```
SELECT t.id,  
       Max(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS MaxVal,
       Min(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS MinVal
 FROM
 (
     SELECT id,  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(vals, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
     FROM  test
 ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
 group by t.id
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22321/6

Comment: what is "Split.a.value..."?

Comment: Split is an alias of table expression produced by Data.nodes ('/M'). `a` is column of that table. It is like `select * from (values(1),(2)) Split(a)`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/manipulating-xml-data-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

select A.id,(select max(item) from dbo.Split(A.vals,',')) as maxvalue,(select min(item) from dbo.Split(A.vals,',')) as minvalue from test A

Create Function For fplit
CREATE FUNCTION Split (
      @InputString                  VARCHAR(8000),
      @Delimiter                    VARCHAR(50)
)

RETURNS @Items TABLE (
      Item                          VARCHAR(8000)
)

AS
BEGIN
      IF @Delimiter = ' '
      BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ','
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
      END

```
  IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
        SET @Delimiter = ','
```

--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Delimiter) -- Diagnostic
--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString) -- Diagnostic

```
  DECLARE @Item                 VARCHAR(8000)
  DECLARE @ItemList       VARCHAR(8000)
  DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

  SET @ItemList = @InputString
  SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
  WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
  BEGIN
        SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
        INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

        -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
        SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
        SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
  END -- End WHILE

  IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
  BEGIN
        SET @Item = @ItemList
        INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
  END

  -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
  ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

  RETURN
```

END -- End Function
GO